# Сообщение об отступах в phpStorm

Tags: php, javascript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, ide

Объясните что означает это сообщение в редакторе: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня нормальный файл, но как я его открываю получаю что то про отступы, чего хочет от меня редактор и о чем предупреждает. Как это можно один раз настроить и не получать подобные сообщения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказано выше, это предложение отформатировать файл в соответствии с настройками IDE (`Settings | Editor | Code Style | <your language>`).
По умолчанию (если включена опция `Detect and use existing file indents for editing` в `Settings | Editor | Code Style`) редактор пытается использовать имеющиеся в файле отступы при работе с файлом (например, если в файле используется табуляция, именно она будет использоваться при редактировании, несмотря на то, что в настройках `Use Tab character` выключена). Но при этом выводится сообщение о несоответствии текущего форматирования найсройкам. Сообщение можно убрать, отключив опцию `Show notifications about detected indents`. Можно изменить настройки Code Style в соответствии с Вашими предпочтениями. Можно просто выключить опцию `Detect and use existing file indents for editing`, и тогда редактор молча будет использовать настройки, и не будет пытаться угадать правильный формат отступа

Comment: а как вы посоветуете делать? своего придерживаться стиля или если в файле свой стиль, позволить редактору использовать его?

Comment: я бы посоветовала использовать стиль, настроенный в IDE - иначе у вас получится разное форматирование в разных файлах. Более того - существующие отступы все равно поменяются на те, что в настройках, если Вы решите все же отформатировать файл (Ctrl+Alt+L).

Answer (score 3):

Это предложение отформатировать файл в соответствие с дефолтными настройками. Комбинация Ctrl+Alt+L (Ctrl+Cmd+L) сделает это автоматически. В настройках всегда можно изменить параметры по умолчанию.